# PHP MYSQL Using 1 id for another table

Tags: php, mysql

Im gonna try to explain what I need to do.

I have a table and in that table I have ID. This ID is my primary key (auto_increment).
And I have a second table.

What I need is when I save something in my seconds table I want to use the ID of my first table.

I have read much things but I only got more headache from it so if anyone could help me with this I would be gratefull.

Rgrds

Comment: Insert into table 1. Get insert id, save it into a variable. Create second query for table 2, using the variable id in the appropriate place. Profit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the concept of a foreign key. This can be defined as a constraint or just used as such. Let's assume you have "Teachers" and "Pupils" and pupils are assigned to one teacher. So the teacher has an `ID`. Now your "Pupils" table has an ID as well (it's primary key) and a foreign key `TEACHER_ID`, which refers to the teacher entry.

```
ALTER TABLE `Pupils` ADD FOREIGN KEY (TEACHER_ID) REFERENCES `Teachers` (ID)
```

will create a constraint, that `TEACHER_ID` refers to the `ID` of a Teacher.

In PHP if you create both entries at once. You can first insert the teacher and then use:

```
$teacherID = mysql_insert_id();
```

which will return you the last `auto_increment` value (in this case your teachers `ID`) and then set this as the `TEACHER_ID` for your pupils entry.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers im sorry for the lack of information.
Peter i am gonna try your answer

Comment: See, that the declaration of a foreign key in MySQL is optional. It's not required to use `mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: problem solved cheers. btw great example :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @id int
SET @id=1

INSERT INTO table2(col1,col2...)
select col1,col2... from table1 where ID=@id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of mySQL you are using with php, but with mysqli  you can use the mysqli_insert_id function (mysql_insert_id also works) example:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
mysqli_query($link, $query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($link));
```

For more information see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php